# Is there an Application Monitor?

Tags: 10.10, software-recommendation, monitoring

I've developed an (awesome) mozilla-based custom web-browser running on Ubuntu 10.10 that needs to always be open (it is basically a "kiosk").

If it crashes, which is easy to do in a single-threaded web-browser like mine, I need it to start right back up (actually, a 10 or so second delay before restarting would be okay).

[Application Monitor](http://www.jockersoft.com/english/appmonitor_index.php) for Windows would be perfect if it wasn't for Windows. I haven't been able to find something, preferably with a GUI, that does this.

I usually develop for Windows based systems so Ubuntu is a bit foreign to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap a bash script around it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
   <execute your browser>
   sleep <specify seconds here>
done
```

Paste it in a file, make it executable (`chmod +x yourfile.sh` or tick the execute box in the file properties in nautilus), double-click it and you should be good to go.